# Long text throws exception

Tags: flutter

I have a text that sometimes may be too long for the screen and a exception is thrown when it is too long for the layout.

Here you have the code:

```
Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'Modesto Vasco Fornasvv v',
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: TextStyle(

                                  fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium",
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 20),
                            ),
```

and here the screenshot:

[image]

I would like to solve the issue, and I have included the line:

```
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
```

but obviously is not enough to solve it.

What should I change or remove to get the text shown whatever lenght it may have?

Comment: you need to wrap it in `Expanded` widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from the UI that you have the `Column` widget inside a `Row` widget. You need to wrap your column widget in an `Expanded` widget for it to calculate that it has to fit the contents of the column in the remaining width of the screen.

Your column widget should like this:

```
Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Modesto Vasco Fornasvv v',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium",
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

This is the code snippet that shows the demo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        /// Added as placeholder for display image
        Container(
          width: 72,
          height: 72,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Modesto Vasco Fornasvv v sadwqdsad asdas dasd asd asdas das das dasdas dasdas dasd',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium",
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap in Expanded widget

```
Expanded(child:Text('Modesto Vasco Fornasvv v',
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium",
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 20),
   ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out **[this](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)** **plugIn** and if it will not work then please wrap it with **Expanded** **widget**

```
AutoSizeText(
  'The text to display',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  maxLines: 1,
)
```